# Making a reactjs input element required by an inline condition

Tags: reactjs

I want to create a required input using a condition which tells me if it's required or not, but am not sure of the syntax.

I'm trying this:

```
<Input
            className='InputElement'
            onValueChange={props.onChange}
            value={props.value}
            {props.isRequired ? required : null}
 />
```

I get a compilation error on `props.isRequired`. I know I can do something like this (pseudo):

```
props.isRequired ? <Input required> : <Input>
```

but I want to do it if possible the way I'm trying in my first example. How can it be done?

Comment: `required` might resolve to boolean, so: `<Input required={props.isRequired} />`

Comment: @user0101 if you want you can add it as an answer and I'll accept it

Comment: No worries, just glad I could help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should work

```
<Input
   className='InputElement'
   onValueChange={props.onChange}
   value={props.value}
   required={props.isRequired}
 />
```